# SSRS 2016 Appears In Directory Browser Mode After Deploying Report From VS 2019

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I installed Reporting Services on SQL Server 2016
I went through the ssrs configuration wizard, and everything was working fine
I was able to go to localhost/ReportingServer, and saw the SSRS reporting manager page

I went into VS 2019 15.4, created a reporting services project by choosing the template that takes you through a wizard to configure the project, created a datasource against a database
I named the project TestReporting
I created a report named Report1

I ran the report from VS, which deployed it to the report server. And the report renders fine, with the URL http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTestReporting%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render

All good so far.

Then I point my browser at http://localhost/ReportServer, and it looks like the reporting server is in directory browsing mode:

[image]

How do I get the original reporting server page back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this thread https://forums.asp.net/t/1446476.aspx?Reports+vs+ReportServer+in+SQL+Reporting+Server

Basically,  /reportServer is the underlying reporting service that houses the reports, and is an endpoint for publishing reports,  and using other services.  /Reports is the actual web portal that you use to browse and execute reports.

Comment: SMH! Cant believe I got that mixed up - worked like a charm - Thanks!